# How to create UISplitViewController's portrait behavior in landscape orientations?

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to find a solution I've seen implemented in some iPad apps where what appears to be a `UISplitViewController` does not display the master view docked to the left in landscape orientation. Instead, the behavior is exactly the same in landscape as in portrait, with a `UIBarButtonItem` on the left side of a `UIToolbar` at the top of the screen bringing up a `UIPopoverController` with the master view controller's view. This presents some menu options that, when selected, appear to launch new `UIViewController`-derived classes into the detail view.

The app I'm working on needs to take advantage of as much screen real estate as possible and having the master view with the menu options docked to the left side doesn't add much value; it actually hinders the app.

So actually what I'm trying to do is two-fold:

1. Suppress the docked master view in landscape orientation
2. Have the selection of a row (menu option) in the master view load a new `UIViewController`-derived class into the detail view.

I've seen examples of each by themselves, respectively:

1. http://vimeo.com/13054813 (Hiding the Root View of a UISplitViewController)
2. http://bit.ly/aypcr0 (MultipleDetailViews code example from Apple)

However, I can't seem to get both of these working together.

The reason for using this approach is that I have multiple `UIViewController`-derived classes that I want to display when the appropriate menu option is selected. I could just instantiate them and add their views to the existing detail view and they would display fine. The problem is that none of the UIViewController lifecycle methods ever get called besides `viewDidLoad` (e.g. `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidUnload`, etc.). This also includes orientation changes, and this is a big problem for the app.  It seems that the only times a `UIViewController`-derived class acts like a `UIViewController` is when it is added as a subview of the app's `UIWindow`, or to a container class (like `UINavigationController` or `UISplitViewController`).

Am I going down the right path with the `UISplitViewController`, or is there a better solution?

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good UISplitViewController replacement that has the features you want (and more).  It is a direct "drop in" replacement for the real UISplitViewConroller.

http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. Took a look at it and it looks fantastic! However, after further analysis, I found it doesn't deliver `UIViewController` lifecycle events (the way it's currently written) to the contained view controllers.  I decided on using a `UITabBarController` as the container instead. It makes more sense since we have distinct areas of functionality of the app and each tab allows our `UIViewController`s to behave properly.  Thanks again for your help, maybe I can use this other implementation in a different app in the future.