# SplitViewController in Landscape Orientation. How Do I Hide the TableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape

On iPad I have a `UISplitViewController`-based app. Has anyone figured out how to hide/show the `tableViewController` that is locked down on the left hand side - when in landscape orientation - stubbornly hogging precious screen real estate?

If you take a look at the iPad Dropbox app it has a nifty show/hide arrow that is exactly what I am after.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180599/how-to-create-uisplitviewcontrollers-portrait-behavior-in-landscape-orientations ntry this out . . .